# character does not attack when i click the mouse

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm new in unity and programing so i don't know what's the problem at all
https://youtu.be/e2PRI19Igbo
I followed this video because i want to make combo attack but when I do the left click, character does not attack[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjfHt.png)
i followe almost everything in video
buy why my character does no attack?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCombat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayerCombat instance;
    public Animator animator;

    public Transform AttackPoint;
    public float AttackRange = 0.5f;
    public LayerMask enemyLayers;

    public int attackDamage = 40;
    public bool canReceiveInput;
    public bool inputReceived;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    void Start()
    {
      
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Attack();
    }
    public void Attack() 
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) 
        {
           if (canReceiveInput) 
            {
                inputReceived = true;
                canReceiveInput = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void InputManager()
    {
        if (!canReceiveInput) 
        {
            canReceiveInput = true;
        }
        else
        {
            canReceiveInput = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a01029431199@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following Anas Essouli answer, it also  seems your problem come with your "canReceiveInput" variable.
When you register a Fire1 input, you check if you have receive the input with your "canReceiveInput" bool var.
But your variable is null at the beginning so it will never pass the condition.
Your `Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")` is enought to launch an attack animation.
Just make sure that there is actual animation or projectile launched and not just code.

Answer (score 0):

in your script there is no animation trigger or attack functionality , you only check if input is Received by the click.